# How to print debug messages in GUI application?

Tags: c++, debugging, printf

I'm building a GUI application with SDL in Codeblocks. Sometimes I need to log (printf/cout) numbers or strings, and I don't know how to do it since it's not a console application.

Is there an alternative way to do this in a gui application? (I don't care where I log to I just need to be able to print and read easily)

Comment: If you run it from a shell, it should work as normal. If not, why not write your stuff to a file?

Comment: SDL automatically outputs to stdout.txt and stderr.txt on Windows, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways I have done this is to add a debug textbox to the GUI. I then append the numbers and strings to it. When development is complete I make it invisible(or delete it).

Comment: thanks, I was going to do this as a last resource. It's strange it's not possible to log to a debug window or something similar, I have coded in java for android before and it was really easy to write logs

Comment: Lately I have been using Sharpdevelop and the IDE has a debug output window. I have never used SDL/Codeblocks, but I'm surprised it doesn't have the same capability.